# SSRS Text Data Output - Header and Details on the same row?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have turned headers off in the report server config file and am attempting to output the header rows above the details in CSV output.  What is happening instead is the header is displaying on the same line as the details.  If I add another table with the header row in it, it works, but leaves a one row gap between the header and the content.  Any help getting this data to line up correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could investigate using XSLT to transform the XML output into a desired format. This is really the only option I know of that I've used in the past for making a custom CSV type output. You could then undo the alteration to the server wide (?) config file as the XSLT file would be applied to just that report, making it easier for deployment

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159716(v=sql.90).aspx

(Probably more up to date links out there, just Google/Bing "SSRS XSLT" etc)

Comment: Yea.  That is really too bad that that is the only solution.  Hopefully in later versions of SSRS table rows will be interpretted by the data renderer as separate rows of data.  Thanks for your help.